# XSL Trouble: Output is missing root element

Tags: xml, xslt, root

I've done a few XSL transformations in the past, but I seem to be out of my depth on this one. Through trial and error I've managed to get nearly the output I'm looking for, but I cannot figure out how to get a root element in my output.

Here is a sample of the XML file input. I need to weed out some unnecessary info and get inside that CDATA.

```
<SI_RESOURCES>
  <SCHEDULES>
    <SCHEDULE>
      <SCHEDULE_TYPE>2</SCHEDULE_TYPE>
      <ASSOCIATED_BP_NAME>AFTPurgeArchiveMailboxes</ASSOCIATED_BP_NAME>
      <ASSOCIATED_SERVICE_NAME>AFTPurgeArchiveMailboxes</ASSOCIATED_SERVICE_NAME>
      <SCHEDULE_PARAMS/>
      <SCHEDULE_ONSTARTUP>1</SCHEDULE_ONSTARTUP>
      <SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_COUNT>-1</SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_COUNT>
      <SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_CURRENT_COUNT>0</SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_CURRENT_COUNT>
      <SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_STATUS>WAIT</SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_STATUS>
      <SCHEDULE_STATUS>ACTIVE</SCHEDULE_STATUS>
      <SCHEDULE_SYSTEMNAME>node1</SCHEDULE_SYSTEMNAME>
      <SCHEDULE_USERID>admin</SCHEDULE_USERID>
      <SCHEDULE_TIMINGXML><![CDATA[<timingxml><days><day ofWeek="-1"><times><time>0400</time></times></day></days><excludedDates></excludedDates></timingxml>]]></SCHEDULE_TIMINGXML>
    </SCHEDULE>
    <SCHEDULE>
      <SCHEDULE_TYPE>1</SCHEDULE_TYPE>
      <ASSOCIATED_BP_NAME>Schedule_AssociateBPsToDocs</ASSOCIATED_BP_NAME>
      <ASSOCIATED_SERVICE_NAME>AssociateBPsToDocs</ASSOCIATED_SERVICE_NAME>
      <SCHEDULE_PARAMS/>
      <SCHEDULE_ONSTARTUP>0</SCHEDULE_ONSTARTUP>
      <SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_COUNT>-1</SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_COUNT>
      <SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_CURRENT_COUNT>0</SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_CURRENT_COUNT>
      <SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_STATUS>WAIT</SCHEDULE_EXECUTION_STATUS>
      <SCHEDULE_STATUS>ACTIVE</SCHEDULE_STATUS>
      <SCHEDULE_SYSTEMNAME>node1</SCHEDULE_SYSTEMNAME>
      <SCHEDULE_USERID>admin</SCHEDULE_USERID>
      <SCHEDULE_TIMINGXML><![CDATA[<timingxml><days><day ofWeek="-1"><times><timeRange><range>0000-2359</range><interval>30</interval><onMinute>0</onMinute></timeRange></times></day></days><excludedDates></excludedDates></timingxml>]]></SCHEDULE_TIMINGXML>
    </SCHEDULE>
  </SCHEDULES>
</SI_RESOURCES>
```

Here is my XSL so far. It's messy, and I'm not entirely sure how it works. I get no output when I use `<xsl:template match="/">` and I'm not sure why. My only guess is that it has something to do with the CDATA.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:for-each select="SCHEDULE">
    &lt;schedule&gt;
        &lt;bp_name&gt;<xsl:value-of select="ASSOCIATED_BP_NAME"/>&lt;/bp_name&gt;
        &lt;run_on_startup&gt;<xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_ONSTARTUP"/>&lt;/run_on_startup&gt;
        &lt;status&gt;<xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_STATUS"/>&lt;/status&gt;
        &lt;user&gt;<xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_USERID"/>&lt;/user&gt;
        <xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_TIMINGXML"/>
    &lt;/schedule&gt;
    </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

I could use the resulting output if it had a root element, ie `<schedules>`, but I can't figure out how to get it over there. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the output to be escaped like that? If yes, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/SI_RESOURCES">
    <schedules>
        <xsl:for-each select="SCHEDULES/SCHEDULE">
            &lt;schedule&gt;
                &lt;bp_name&gt;<xsl:value-of select="ASSOCIATED_BP_NAME"/>&lt;/bp_name&gt;
                &lt;run_on_startup&gt;<xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_ONSTARTUP"/>&lt;/run_on_startup&gt;
                &lt;status&gt;<xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_STATUS"/>&lt;/status&gt;
                &lt;user&gt;<xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_USERID"/>&lt;/user&gt;
                <xsl:value-of select="SCHEDULE_TIMINGXML"/>
            &lt;/schedule&gt;
        </xsl:for-each>
    </schedules>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That worked! I did have to change `<schedules>` to `&lt;schedules&gt;` to get it to work for some reason, but I can live with that. Thank you for your help!